# WPF dragblz Finding TabItem to Re-Add

Tags: c#, wpf

ok Im not sure if this issue is related to the library or me being still being new to WPF .but , I'm using the dragablz library and I am trying to re-add a tab after tearing it then closing that specfic window. However , I cant seem to find all the TabItem when ever I try to search for it in the grid of the current winodw I get nothing , this what I treid.

```
<Window x:Class="TeheMan8_Editor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TeheMan8_Editor"
        xmlns:dragablz="http://dragablz.net/winfx/xaml/dragablz"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <dragablz:TabablzControl Name="tabHub" AllowDrop="True" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
                <dragablz:InterTabController />
            </dragablz:TabablzControl.InterTabController>
            <TabItem Name="mainTab" Header="Tab No. 1" IsSelected="True">
                <Button Click="Button_Click">Open FileButton</Button>
            </TabItem>
        </dragablz:TabablzControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CSharp Code:

```
using DiscUtils.Iso9660;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TeheMan8_Editor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var items = this.grid.Children.OfType<TabItem>(); //returns Empty

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

never mind I figured it out , the TabablzControl Object has a OfType function for the  "Items.SouceCollection" property